# Can we drag and expand the column or row from grid in .net MAUI

Tags: .net, .net-maui

I want to design table where I can drag and expand the columns is it possible in .net MAUI?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no easy, built-in, way to do this. At this time, you might need to purchase a data grid from a third-party vendor. Alternatively, writing such a control from scratch, would be a major effort. You could go to [CommunityToolkit/Maui](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui) and suggest it as a "Feature Request". You could also suggest it to [Freaky Ali/Maui.FreakyControls](https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls) - he has some open source controls. Nothing like this, but he might be interested in tackling the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is something called DataGrid.  It looks a lot like an Excel sheet/Google Sheet with resizable columns.  I believe you can also resize the rows.  I have not used it personally, but I believe it works similarly to the GridView class.  DataGrid is fully supported in MAUI.